# Ruby 1.8 not showing on the command line

Tags: ruby, command-line, ubuntu-10.04

I have installed ruby1.8 on my Ubuntu machine from the command line. But the system shows ruby has not been installed.

Here is the console ouptput:

```
frank@my-version3:~/apps$ sudo apt-get install ruby1.8 ruby1.8-dev irb rdoc ri
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ruby1.8 is already the newest version.
ruby1.8-dev is already the newest version.
irb is already the newest version.
rdoc is already the newest version.
ri is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

frank@my-version3:~/apps$ which ruby

frank@my-version3:~/apps$ ruby -v
-bash: ruby: command not found

frank@my-version3:~/apps$ ruby
-bash: ruby: command not found

frank@my-version3:~/apps$ irb
irb(main):001:0> exit

frank@my-version3:~/apps$
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: are you getting same error when you open new console? hv u check it after restart your m/c?

Comment: Yes. Still getting the same thing.

Comment: try running `ruby1.8` as opposed to just `ruby`  also `ls -l /usr/bin/ruby*`  and see if you see anything

Comment: @Doon Running using `ruby1.8` works OK. Thanks. How can I make it in such a way that I can use `ruby` instead of `ruby1.8`?

Comment: try `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: don't do the symlink  see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use update-alternatives do to this

```
update-alternatives --set ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

for a list of alternatives

```
update-alternatives --query ruby
```

**UPDATE:** For users who might experience the same problem, see [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10057489)

Answer (score 0):

Can you see ruby in /usr/bin after 'cd'ing to it?  You can also run *echo $PATH* to see if your path is set properly.